# Laravel - access get variables passed with?

Tags: laravel, function, parameters, get

how can i access the variable passed after the `?` from within a function?

```
https://www.somesite.com/2AAAJK1/D1CDD52A/IMG_4432-Modifica.png/fancybox?file=%2Fimages%2F2AMJJK1%2FD1C8652A%2F4a3d68%2F%2FIMG_4432-Modifica.png
```

I am able to read all the variables in the path, except for the file..

tried this: `public function fancybox($phcode , $galcode, $imgname, $file)`

but it does not work.. $file is empty.

Comment: Please share the route you are using to reach your `fancybox()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `public function fancybox(Request $request)` then in this `$request` you can get all the variables that are in you request like so.

```
$request->phcode
$request->galcode
$request->imgname
$request->file
```

And if the file is actually some file that you have uploaded then you can try to get the file object with following way.

```
if( $request->hasfile('file_name) ){
$file = $request->file('file_name);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to pass parameter.

```
 https://www.somesite.com/2AAAJK1/D1CDD52A/IMG_4432-Modifica.png/fancybox?file=%2Fimages%2F2AMJJK1%2FD1C8652A%2F4a3d68%2F%2FIMG_4432-Modifica.png
```

If you are passing this way, it will be part of the request..then you should use `$request->input('file')`

```
 https://www.somesite.com/2AAAJK1/D1CDD52A/IMG_4432-Modifica.png/fancybox/{%2Fimages%2F2AMJJK1%2FD1C8652A%2F4a3d68%2F%2FIMG_4432-Modifica.png}
```

if you are passing like this, you can use directly, because it is part of the url.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `request('file')` helper.
For more detailed information [Laravel Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-request)